# Angular 5 , Mapear um array de Objetos dentro de outro array de Objetos

Tags: array, angular, typescript, objetos, angular-5

Bom eu estou tentando encapsular meus Objetos.
O primeiro Objeto ele mapeia o primeiro array do JSON.

```
export interface PraticarObject {

    id_assunto: number;
    nome_assunto: string;
    qt_exercicios_concluidos: string;
    conteudos: ConteudosPraticarArray[];
}
```

bom até ai tudo bem, eu consigo obter o id_assuntos nome_assunto, qt_exercicios, porem quando eu tento obter o conteudos.

ele me retorna assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a classe ConteudosPraticarArray esta assim.

```
export interface ConteudosPraticarArray {

 id_conteudo: string;
 nome_conteudo: string;
}
```

eu estou usando o metodo Observable na api para preencher o PraticarObject.

bom o problema é que ele me traz o Object e não consigo utilizá-lo . :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por conteúdos serem do tipo ConteudosPraticarArray[] (`conteudos: ConteudosPraticarArray[];`), e esse ultimo ser um array de Objetos, você precisa acessá-lo assim como acessa o `id_assunto` da Classe PraticarObject por exemplo.

Exemplo:

```
export interface ConteudosPraticarArray {
    id_conteudo: string;
    nome_conteudo: string;
}
export interface PraticarObject {
    id_assunto: number;
    nome_assunto: string;
    qt_exercicios_concluidos: string;
    conteudos: ConteudosPraticarArray[];
}
```

Para acessar o nome do conteúdo eu devo colocar:

```
/*Aqui abaixo, irei criar objetos para exemplificar, dependerá de como o seu código está*/
    var conteudo1 = new ConteudosPraticarArray (1,'Conteudo 1')
    var conteudo2 = new ConteudosPraticarArray (2,'Conteudo 2')
    var po = new PraticarObject(1,'Assunto Número 1', 15, [conteudo1,conteudo2])
/*AQUI A DEMONSTRAÇÃO DE COMO VOCÊ PODE RECEBER O VALOR "nome_conteudo" DOS CONTEÚDOS, E NÃO MAIS OBJETOS COMO ESTAVA ACONTECENDO*/
    console.log(po.conteudos[0].nome_conteudo) /*ESSA LINHA ME RETORNARÁ "Conteudo 1"*/
    console.log(po.conteudos[1].nome_conteudo) /*ESSA LINHA ME RETORNARÁ "Conteudo 2"*/
```